# Воспроизведение звука с помощью QSound

Tags: qt, linux

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему нижеприведенный код не воспроизводит звуки на Линуксе?

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QSound> 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 QApplication app(argc, argv);
 QSound *obj = new QSound("/home/user/checkers/sound.wav");
 obj->play();
 return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Что дает QSound::isAvailable?

Comment: Возвращает false. Как узнать, в чем именно проблема?

Comment: Этот вопрос одно время на многих форумах обсуждался. Вероятнее, всего не установлена / не включена система [NAS](http://radscan.com/nas.html), используемая Qt для вывода через QSound.

Почему не использовать Phonon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

есть вероятность, что приложение завершится раньше, чем выполнится метод play()...